# Can we take photo of a mirage?

Tags: geometric-optics

I do know that mirages are optical illusions . I know the phenomenon of its formation just tell me if we can ?

Comment: [Photographs of mirages](https://www.google.co.uk/search?tbm=isch&q=mirage)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because of insufficient effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume what you are asking is whether the phenomena which cause mirages are happening inside our head, as with some other optical effects, or whether they are 'out there' in the world.  In the former case the image made by a camera would fail to objectively record the effect, although looking at it might still cause us to experience the same thing (this is the case, for instance, with the famous 'grey blob' effect that our visual system fools us into seeing in some chequerboard patterns: there's nothing there really, but you still see it in a photographic image).

And the answer to this is that mirages are quite definitely physical artifacts which are out there in the world and not artifacts of our visual system.  And so cameras record them very happily: an image search will show many examples.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The eye and the camera work with the same optics, the camera registers on the film, the eye on the retina.

[image: iceberg mirage]

[The mirage](http://didyouknow.org/you-can-take-photographs-of-mirages/) of an iceberg. Another [iceberg mirage.](https://graphics.stanford.edu/courses/cs348b-competition/cs348b-05/mirage/iceberg.html)

[Lots of  mirage photos](http://www.alamy.com/stock-photo/mirages.html)